# Сервер не видит файлы изображений

Tags: javascript, html

Есть скрипт, который формирует ссылку на изображение в зависимости от значения выбранного в выпадающем списке `<select>`.

Вот он:

```
function showImage() {
    var items = document.getElementsByClassName("item");
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        items[i].addEventListener("change", func);
    }
}

function func(event) {
    var row = event.target.parentNode.parentNode;
    var itemValue = row.querySelector(".item").value;
    var itemNum = itemList.indexOf(itemValue);
    if (itemNum == 0) {
        row.querySelector(".image").innerHTML = "";
    } else {
        row.querySelector(".image").innerHTML = 
                '<img alt="" class="img-rounded" width="150" src="static/' + (itemNum - 1) + '.jpg">';
    }
}
```

Работает он правильно и выдает такую вещь:

```
<img alt="" class="img-rounded" width="150" src="static/4.jpg">
```

Сервер же утверждает, что изображения по указанному адресу
`example.com/static/4.jpg` нет.
Но файл этот точно есть по указанному адресу.
Если этот проект запустить на локальном тестовом сервере, то всё работает правильно.
В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Попробуй так `row.querySelector(".image").innerHTML = 
  '<img alt="" class="img-rounded" width="150" src="'+window.location.protocol+'//'+location.hostname+'/static/'+(itemNum-1)+'.jpg">';`

Comment: Увы, не получается. Путь получается правильный, но сервер по-прежнему не видит картинки. Проверил права на чтение - с ними все окей.

Comment: а вы возьмите и засуньте exemple.com/static/4.jpg (я понимаю что это символическая ссылка для примера ) в адресную строку броузера , она откроется ?

Comment: Все тот же 404 в ответ получаю...

Comment: `404` даже при обычном открытии? Если так то проверьте возможно под данный адрес попадают правила в `rewrite` ? Для `nginx` они обычно в `nginx.conf` а для `Apache` в файле `.htaccess`  в корне сайта

Comment: Даже при обычном открытии. `example.com/static/2.jpg` выдаст `404`, а `example.com/static/showimg.js` прекрасно открывается. Конфигов я пока нужных не нашел, буду копать еще как-нибудь.

Comment: Похоже проблема в конфигурации сервера

Comment: Там всего пара файлов конфига, но в них про ssh и python. Хостниг `pythonanywhere` + вэб-приложение на Bottle. Может кто-то сталкивался?

Comment: А какой хостинг вы используете?

Comment: Дело скорее всего в конфигурации сервера, сталкивался с такой проблемой года 2 назад. Использовал тогда IDHost. В нем были проблемы с некоторыми картинками которые так и не удалось решить, т.к. на бесплатном тарифе не предоставляется возможности самостоятельно конфигурировать сервер.

Comment: Pythonanywhere. Техподдержка решила вопрос. Проблема была в регистрозависимости. Файлы изображений почему-то были в верхнем регистре, а скрипт вставлял в тег в нижнем, поэтому сервер не видел картинки. И поэтому их нельзя было увидеть по прямому адресу, так как я забивал их в нижнем регистре.